# Include a File If a Condition Is Met Inside Apache Ant fileset

Tags: java, ant, conditional-statements

Is there a way to `include` or `exclude` certain files based on a condition in Apache Ant (1.8.3)? For instance, I have a `macrodef` that takes an attribute. I would like to `include` certain files if the attribute's value matches `xyz`:

```
<macrodef name="pkgmacro">
    <attribute name="myattr" />
    <sequential>
         <zip destfile="${dist}/@{myattr}.war">
             <fileset dir="${dist}/webapp" >     
                 <include name="**/@{myattr}/**" />
                 <exclude name="WEB-INF/config/**" /> 
                 <!-- if @{myattr} = "xyz", then
                 <include name="PATH/TO/file.xml" />
                 -->                    
             </fileset>
             <zipfileset dir="${ear}/@{myattr}/WEB-INF/" includes="*.xml" prefix="WEB-INF/" />
         </zip>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

For instance, if `myattr` value is `xyz`, I would like to `include` the commented file in portion above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fileset can use [nested include/exlucde patternsets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html) with if/unless
Attribute. The pattern is included/excluded when a named property is set or not, so no ant addons needed.
Some snippet :

```
<project>

 <!-- property that triggers your include/exclude
      maybe set via condition in some other target .. -->
 <property name="foo" value="bar"/>

 <macrodef name="pkgmacro">
  <attribute name="myattr" />
   <sequential>
    <fileset dir="C:/whatever" id="foobar">
     <!-- alternatively
     <include name="*.bat" unless="@{myattr}"/>
     -->
     <include name="*.bat" if="@{myattr}"/>
    </fileset>
    <!-- print fileset contents -->
    <echo>${toString:foobar}</echo>
   </sequential>
 </macrodef>

 <pkgmacro myattr="foo"/>

</project>
```

**--EDIT after comment --**

The `if/unless attribute` after `include name/exclude name` checks whether the given value is a property which is set (when using if="..") or not set (when using unless="..") in the ant project scope - it doesn't check for a specific value.
`<include name="*.xml" unless="foo"/>` 
means include is only active if ***no*** property named foo is set in your project
`<include name="*.xml" if="foo"/>` 
means include is only active if property named foo is set in your project

Works fine for me , used Ant 1.7.1, had no Ant 1.8.x around right now :

```
<project>

 <echo>$${ant.version} => ${ant.version}</echo>

 <macrodef name="pkgmacro">
   <attribute name="myattr"/>
   <sequential>
     <condition property="pass">
      <equals arg1="@{myattr}" arg2="xyz" />
     </condition>
    <fileset dir="C:/whatever" id="foobar">
     <include name="*.bat" if="pass" />
    </fileset>
    <echo>${toString:foobar}</echo>
   </sequential>   
 </macrodef>

<pkgmacro myattr="xyz"/>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] ${ant.version} => Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008
[echo] switchant.bat;foobar.bat;foo.bat
```

**-- EDIT after comment --**
Using serveral include patterns works fine :

```
...
<fileset dir="C:/whatever" id="foobar">
 <include name="*.xml" if="pass" />
 <include name="*.bat" if="pass"/>
 <include name="**/*.txt" if="pass"/>
</fileset>
...
```

maybe you're using the wrong patterns ?

**-- EDIT after comment --**

[Here is the reference](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) to `<local>` task which is needed to work with the properties in the current scope, in this case, `<sequential>`:

```
 <macrodef name="pkgmacro">
   <attribute name="myattr"/>
   <sequential>
     <!-- make property pass mutable -->
     <local name="pass"/>
     <condition property="pass">
      <equals arg1="@{myattr}" arg2="xyz" />
     </condition>
    <fileset dir="C:/whatever" id="foobar">
     <include name="*.xml" if="pass" />
      <include name="*.bat" if="pass" />
      <include name="**/*.txt" if="pass" />
    </fileset>
    <!-- print value of property pass and fileset contents -->
    <echo>$${pass} = ${pass}${line.separator}${toString:foobar}</echo>
   </sequential>   
 </macrodef>
```

Comment: I am still not sure how `if` (or `unless`) of `include` is doing the actual comparison with the value of `@{myattr}`. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I tried `<sequential><condition property="pass"><equals arg1="@{myattr}" arg2="xyz" /></condition><fileset dir="C:/whatever" id="foobar"><include name="*.bat" if="pass"/></fileset></sequential>` however, it seems like for every `@{myattr}`, it includes `*.bat` (and if `unless` is used, it excludes all even when `@{myattr}` is indeed `xyz`!

Comment: So, I had tried the followup solution (my comment above) before your latest update, but I discovered that if I call `pkgmacro` with several values consecutively, i.e. `abc`, `def`, `xyz`, `zwu`, the first two calls _do not_ get the file included. However, anything after `xyz`, in this case, `zwu`, do get the file included! Why?

Comment: you mean using several <include name="..." if="..."/> pattern parallel ?     <fileset dir="C:/whatever" id="foobar">
     <include name="*.xml" if="pass" />
     <include name="*.bat" if="pass"/>
     <include name="**/*.txt" if="pass"/>
    </fileset> works fine. Maybe you're using the wrong patterns ?

Comment: the comment prints the wrong patternsyntax, so see edit in answer

Comment: Thanks. Let me clarify my previous comment. Given I call `<pkgmacro>` multiple times with different values, say, inside a `target`: `<pkgmacro myattr="abc" /><pkgmacro myattr="def" /><pkgmacro myattr="xyz" /><pkgmacro myattr="zwu" />`. The first two won't going to have the file included, but the last two would. So, in case of `zwu`, we should not have gotten the file included. It seems like, once the condition is set inside of `<sequence>`, it stays set for the remaining calls.

Comment: That's because properties in ant are immutable once set, you need to use the <local> task - available since Ant 1.8 - see my edit

Answer (score 2):

if you can use ant-contrib, then try this:

```
<contrib:if>
    <equals arg1="${myattr}" arg2="xyz" />
    <then>
        <include name="PATH/TO/file.xml" />
    </then>
</contrib:if>
```

if you can't use ant-contrib, try this:

http://jaysonlorenzen.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/apache-ant-if-else-condition-without-ant-contrib/

Comment: Thank you, however, I cannot use any external library.